# Is there a way to search value in a column through app script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am new to app scripting. My question is I have two columns.  In one column there is an id and in the second column the count which is 0 for all the rows.
There will be a user input where user will give an input for what id he wants to search. If the id matches then count will be 1 in the same row where the id is found.

Comment: Please share a copy of your spreadsheet, and include an example of a successful outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your sheet looks like this -

[image: demo sheet]

And the expected behavior is that every time someone searches the ID, the count should increase by 1 - this part is unclear in OP; i.e. if the count is supposed to stay constant at 1 or if its supposed to increase by 1 so as to asset the # of times that ID has been searched.

This is the script that you can use (the script would **increase the count by 1**)

```
function myFunction() {

  var searchID = 'A1'; // modify this to any other ID to test

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var values = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  var headers = values[0];
  var idIndex = headers.indexOf('ID');
  var countIndex = headers.indexOf('Count');
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][idIndex] == searchID) {
      var sheetRow = i+1;
      var count = ss.getRange(sheetRow, countIndex+1).getValue(); // comment this if not required
      ss.getRange(sheetRow, countIndex+1).setValue(count+1); // replace "count+1" with just 1 if the above line is excluded
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: can i get your email? i need some more help . i hope you will help me

Comment: I'm glad this helped. Please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) too :) I'm also reachable via `code@script.gs`